# Does this kind of time travel exist?

Tags: time-travel

**WARNING: If this question is off-topic or in any way a bad question for this site, please don't downvote it, but migrate it to where it belongs. I cannot find an adequate place for this question, but I would love to get a proper answer for it instead of many downvotes which would prevent it from being answered by those who are willing to answer.**

Say you can't change the past which affects you, but you can change everything else. I think that that already exists. However, a crazy idea came to my mind.

Imagine if, for example in real world, you go back to the past, say year 1, but into a jungle which had no contact with the world you live in since the point in time to which you're travelling and the point where you have gone back to the past. Could it be possible to rebuild the whole world's technology, culture, politics, religion, everything by preaching about how the world should be to the tribes. They accept and you tell them you will come back and so you travel every 50 years towards the future to see if everything is okay and if the society hasn't screwed up. You do so until you reach 2001 where you jump to 2018 and tell the tribes that they're ready to open to the outer world. Let's say that they cannot make any contact with the world due to spacetime restricting them from influencing anything that influences you until 2018 where you went back to the past in the first place.

So with your tribe, the technology is more advanced than that of the world you know. You have nanotechnology with blockchain AI microscopic cells that act like a "magic wand field" meaning that when you say "Food, spawn!", the particles listen to you and craft the food from subatomic particles and whatnot. So you start bringing forth awesome miracles and come to contact with your own world. Would they believe that you've invented everything before them? Would they abolish patents because you've "invented everything before them"? How would this happen? Say you also have powers to do with your world whatever you want. For example, wiping out all terrorists instantaneously or spawning food for every poor person or capturing the world elite to expose them to the world? Could you be able to cause world peace if you were genuinely fighting for world peace and if you had all the power to do it?

But most importantly, does such an idea already exist?

Comment: "*does such an idea already exist?*"  Sure it does, **in your head**.  But "this kind of time travel" doesn't really exist.  Thus, I'm confused by your question.

Comment: @RonJohn I think he means "Has anyone else used this concept before in writing", which is a valid question but one that I think could be better answered at the Writing SE. Since he asked for it to be migrated rather than deleted, I feel like moving it to Writing SE is what we should do with this question.

Comment: I highly doubt Writing SE can answer this. But the Movies/Fantasy one might be able to since IIRC they allow for questions where you post a plot and ask for the book/movie name

Comment: Looks like migration is the best move here! That is, if the OP means does the idea already exist *in literature/film!*

Comment: I don't think this would be in topic in any of the stacks mentioned so far. It is also off-topic here. I think even sites like Quora wouldn't take it well.

Comment: I went to the SciFi and searched for timetravel questions, but everyone has questions about existing movies and not about some new ideas. When I ask "does X exist" in this case, I mean to say "has anyone made it into an already known literature/film/video game?".

Comment: And yes, please migrate my question, but I don't know where exactly.

Comment: @Foxcat385 so by that do you mean you haven't asked the question there yet? It might be worth manually moving the question yourself (by reposting this question, or cutting out the specific part of the question you're asking and pasting it on Scifi.SE) and seeing if they take it well. It might work, even if it's a little unconventional for the site.

Comment: Or maybe you could direct me to a website which supports off-topic, non-specific, speculation-ish topics for discussion of various concepts. I'm really not good at asking something with a specific answer. I've failed at many SE sites. StackOverflow doesn't take me seriously enough and I've had many moments where I couldn't ask questions anymore.

Comment: @Foxcat385 Try Quora or Yahoo! Answers

Comment: by the way, downvotes do not prevent answers

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is not a worldbuilding question, it's a meta question couched in a question about a character's actions. Further, unless I'm misreading something this is just an example of going back in time to alter the past in ways that don't change your history, which the OP outright states "I think this exists already".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you have a bunch of different questions all together but I'd like to point out a flaw in what you've said.

You time travel back to develop a culture that won't influence you so there will be no time line problems. You take back technology and have them develop it in secret while remaining hidden from the world and that is where the problem lies. There is a huge amount of resources required to develop any tribe or country onto the same level as we are right now, and most importantly it requires a huge amount of space. Your going to huge mines to be able to supply the raw materials required to build an advance society and huge amounts of room to produce food, process materials and manufacture it. They would of had to have been spotted by some other country and once their power is discovered then they would integrate into the world and affect your timeline. There would be no way of advancing so far without having a magical technology like Wakandas vibranium and invisibility shield and this brings up the next problem.

You as a time traveler would not be able to develop the country further than you have currently traveled. If you want more advance technologies, you need to travel into the future and since you now exist and have influenced a part of the future, your hidden country will now have to wait until that date so there won't be any influence. So no matter when your hidden country reveals itself, its tech level won't end up much better unless they develop it themselves, but that leads to the first point with them having to be able to acquire massive amount of materials and their own research while being isolated.

If they are successfully introduced and have the same technology level they would probably be sued into oblivion. They would be able to trace back the introduction and development of technology and it would all lead back to you. It would be discovered that you have time traveled and sent back all the technology. Why? because papers magically appeared with instructions which covered principles and developments that took anywhere between years to decades to develop. Disregarding that, there have often been many things that have been re-invented or discovered at the same time and often the one that is more well known will stick, like Edison inventing the Light bulb, but he actually popularized it. If anything, your new country would probably successfully integrate into the world and replace their history and development with the real worlds version as they would notice many of the conflicts.

Comment: Very well formed! Thank you! These are the answers I've been waiting for!

Comment: I think they'd be safe legally. There's no precedent, which slows legal action down a lot. Most of the patents you'd be breaking would be so old that they had expired by the time the tribe joined the rest of the world, and most of the patent owners would not be around any more to press charges. If those that are around and do have active patents tried to press charges, any good lawyer would bring up the fact that technically the tribe had the information before the patent owner, which makes our laws nonsensical, and no jury would punish the tribe for things their distant ancestors did.

Comment: A caveat for my previous comment: That all changes if the rest of the world gets access you your time-traveling ability/tech. In that case laws are likely to be adapted much more quickly, and it may be possible to penalize the ancestors themselves.

Comment: @Josh However they didnt create the ideas themselves even if they had access to it. Chances are there wont be any major affects however they will most likely be forced to pay royalties if they want to sell it to a broader community. There isnt any laws covering it, but someone elses work was stolen and given away and the exact same patent would be a major give away.

Answer (score 3):

There's three sets of questions here.

First, the time travel question.  Yes, this is a very typical time travel mechanism.  It's usually implemented as separate timelines.  You can move up from timeline n to any time in timeline n+1 (including the "past"), and it looks like you also need to be able to travel into the future of timeline n.  Alternatively, watch the movie Primer to see a far more exotic and fascinating way to approach it.  12 monkeys did an approach similar to this, and The Butterfly Effect did another take.

The only difference between this typical structure and yours is that you seem to be trying to do it within one "world."  That could be tricky because you are 100% certain to interact with yourself on these timescales due to chaos theory.  Permutation City is an excellent book which explores what happens when the structure of the universe is designed to prevent information from group X from being transferred to group Y.

The second set is "how would society respond."  This depends entirely on how you introduce the tech.  It could be anything from welcoming a savior to declaring you to be humanity's enemy-number one.  No answer can really be given.

The third set is "can I do ridiculously difficult task X with magically high technology."  The answer is... maybe.  Technology is cool, but world peace is a notoriously difficult thing to achieve, and it's often been noted that it's not desirable to pay the price required to achieve it.

The final thing i'd note is that your approach involves skipping ahead 50 years many many many times.  If you ever fall off the rails, you'll have to start over from the prehistoric era again, and teach everyone how to do these magical things, again.  If you can manage to keep society on track for 500 years by interacting with it once every 50 years, you are doing something *utterly* astonishing.  If you could do that, you could skip the whole timetravel thing and just try for world peace directly, because being able to do that is just that amazing.  Doing it for 2000 years?  You are already a deity, without the timetravel.

No seriously... peace on earth is something that they tried back around the year 1.  Whether that worked or not is really up to you and your religion.

Comment: So what you're saying is that a single movement of my breath causes the air molecules to vibrate differently which cascadedly in a domino effect over the years affects all the winds in the world and causes, for example, a tornado happen which didn't happen in my past, but suddenly happens and I'm influenced as soon as it appears on my TV in let's say 2010. Right? Well formed. Thank you for telling me this. However, I was using a special theory where no matter what I do, I won't be able to change my history because some abstract spacetime law wouldn't let me; call it predestination if you will.

Comment: @Foxcat385 Then what happens depends *entirely* on what that special spacetime law does.  However, if it does function properly, it will behave exactly like the different labeled timelines.  If it functions in undersirable ways, you might find that you permanently restrict your ability to do anything, and become a vegetable.  It all depends on the laws.

Comment: @Foxcat385 _"no matter what I do, I won't be able to change my history because some abstract spacetime law wouldn't let me"_ => The Time Machine (2002 film) with Guy Pearce is depicting this issue. I don't want to spoil but I think you should watch it.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, taking everything into consideration, that you are able to actually communicate with the tribe in year 1 and teach them all you know..... well.. even despite that you can only tell them their future and the bits of trade knowledge you have. After that humanity has to learn everything on their own as you can only tell them the future. maybe a few things could be progressed better as you could tell them what NOT to do but still people learn from error so if they never tried that rout and never learned from that error they may not have discovered some other vital things though different things may have been discovered in its stead.

to answer the questions in order:

- Q1: probably not unless you were distinctly remembered in records and even  then you could be an identical offspring claiming to be said person.
- Q2:technically no, they would still invent patients because you never really created it unless you did indeed have some patience but not all as no one person can contain it all.
- Q3:self answered by Q2
  *adding super powers of god like abilities* ...*loading*
- Q4:*is not a question but ill answer the entire ending here*. No world would be at complete peace because bad elements will always exist, due to human or not human nature (depending on creatures you create is in a story) so there fore there can be a type of world peace, but will never truly be at peace, someone will always rise up against the good. though you may indeed avoid an all out world war and only deal with civil issues.
- Q5: its not entirely an unheard of idea that I am aware of, time travel and changing the past to bring a brighter future is a common desire for many people but I don't know that anyone has patented the idea on paper or in digital.

cheers, E.M.

Comment: Thank you for your specific answers. Thank you also for the ideas about morality.

Answer (score 1):

Forget your technology or what you plan to do. Your problem is what to do with paradoxes, the whole "What happens if I go back in time and kill my father"

There are really two main ways for time travel to not make paradoxes. You have fixed time where you can go back in time but you cannot change time. You try and kill your father but the gun jams, you miss, time machine fails, something happens to prevent you from changing time. The movie [12 Monkeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Monkeys) is like this.

The other option is the multiverse theory where traveling back in time spawns off a new reality so you can kill your father or at least the version of your father in this new universe. Since it's not really your father (from your timeline), no paradoxes are created.

Once you work out how your time travel works, how you apply it is up to you.

Comment: But the thing here is that I'm NOT AFFECTING my own grandfather. In my theory (or someone's. I forgot who it was), a person going back to the past cannot change the already done events nor can they spawn another timeline, but only use up the opportunities that don't affect the younger person. You can only come back to the past to get the opportunities that do not affect your current self and that's what I'm doing here. You basically travel back to a jungle that has NO CONTACT with your ancestors, but your jungle influences your world AFTER the point of time where you went back to the past.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The fact you're going back in time has the potential to change time simply from the bacteria hopping off your skin to the ant you tread on. Simply going back will change time.